# Not getting the expected result with IBM Watson Speech To Text

Tags: python, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

When trying to test an mp3 file on a standard IBM Watson S2T model, I get the following output:

```
<bound method DetailedResponse.get_result of <ibm_cloud_sdk_core.detailed_response.DetailedResponse object at 0x00000250B1853700>>
```

Which is not an error, but also not my desired output.

This is my code:

```
api = IAMAuthenticator(api_key)
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(authenticator=api)

speech_to_text.set_service_url(url)

with open(mp3-file, "rb") as audio_file:
    result = speech_to_text.recognize(
        model='de-DE_BroadbandModel', audio=audio_file, content_type="audio/mp3"
    ).get_result

print(result)
```

I am very new to this topic and have not really figured out what the parameters are yet. I hoped to have an output like

```
{'result': [...]}
```

I followed [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZTIjEjeJmwU).
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's the code that worked for me using a sample `audio_file2.mp3`

```
import json
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{api_key}')
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    authenticator=authenticator
)

speech_to_text.set_service_url('{url}')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'audio-file2.mp3'),
               'rb') as audio_file:
    speech_recognition_results = speech_to_text.recognize(
        audio=audio_file,
        content_type='audio/mp3',
        word_alternatives_threshold=0.9
    ).get_result()
print(json.dumps(speech_recognition_results, indent=2))
```

**Steps:**

1. Once you create the Watson [Speech-to-Text service](https://cloud.ibm.com/catalog/services/speech-to-text)
2. Replace `{url}` and `{api_key}` in the Python code with speech-to-text service credentials.
3. Save the file with the code as `speech-to-text.py`.
4. From a command prompt or a terminal, run `pip install ibm-watson` and then `python speech-to-text.py` to see the result similar to the one shown below

Refer the [speech-to-text api docs](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text?code=python#recognize) for more options.

```
{
  "result_index": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "final": true,
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "a line of severe thunderstorms with several possible tornadoes is approaching Colorado on Sunday ",
          "confidence": 1.0
        }
      ],
      "word_alternatives": [
        {
          "start_time": 0.2,
          "end_time": 0.35,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "a",
              "confidence": 0.94
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 0.35,
          "end_time": 0.69,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "line",
              "confidence": 0.94
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 0.69,
          "end_time": 0.78,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "of",
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 0.78,
          "end_time": 1.13,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "severe",
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 1.13,
          "end_time": 1.9,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "thunderstorms",
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 4.0,
          "end_time": 4.18,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "is",
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 4.18,
          "end_time": 4.63,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "approaching",
              "confidence": 1.0
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 4.63,
          "end_time": 5.21,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "Colorado",
              "confidence": 0.93
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 5.21,
          "end_time": 5.37,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "on",
              "confidence": 0.93
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 5.37,
          "end_time": 6.09,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "Sunday",
              "confidence": 0.94
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: With this solution I get the error `raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable`

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python version 3.8, running on windows

Comment: Can you just run `print(speech_recognition_results)` and paste the response here?

Comment: `<bound method DetailedResponse.get_result of <ibm_cloud_sdk_core.detailed_response.DetailedResponse object at 0x000001E27CBC3700>>
`

Comment: I made 2 changes and now it works:
- I used another audio file (.flac)
- prior my variable was called 'result', now I changed it to 'speech_recognition_results'. I am not sure which of both changes was the important one.

Comment: Oh good. Can you mark this as an answer if it helped?

Comment: It would have been neither. It would have the the unintentional 3rd change you made by adding a pair of brackets allowing you to invoke the method, rather than setting `result` to be an alias to the method. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

`get_result` is a method, so you need to invoke it. You are printing out the method, and not invoking it. Hence your output is showing

```xml
<bound method DetailedResponse.get_result ...
```

A couple of brackets should fix it.

```py
with open(mp3-file, "rb") as audio_file:
    result = speech_to_text.recognize(
        model='de-DE_BroadbandModel', audio=audio_file, content_type="audio/mp3"
    ).get_result()
```